# Find all triples of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ satisfying $(a^3+b)(b^3+a)=2^c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all triples of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ satisfying $$(a^3+b)(b^3+a)=2^c$$

All the "solutions" I saw are **long with many subcases**. Since this is a problem from Turkey TST for Junior Balkan MO, i suspect there must be some **simple** solution. My first idea was to write $$a^3+b = 2^x \;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\;\;b^3+a=2^y\;\;\;(*)$$

If $a=b$ then we have $a(a^2+1)=2^x=2^y$ so $a=2^z$ where $x>z$ and then $2^{2z}+1 = 2^{x-z}$. Clearly $x-z>2z$ so $1= 2^{2z}(2^{x-3z}-1)$, so $z=0$ and $2^x=2 \implies x=1=y$, so $c=2$ and $a=b= 1$.

Wlog $a<b $ so $2\leq x<y$. Then we can write (subtract equations $*$) $$(b-a)(a^2+ab+b^2-1) = 2^x(2^{y-x}-1)$$ From here we have many possibilities and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just noticed that Noam Elkies posted an answer here, so I was confident. Should have checked anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that (at least) one between $a$ and $b$ is even, then, since $a^3+b,b^3+a > 1$ and they are both powers of $2$, the other one must be even as well. Say that $\alpha = v_2(a) > 0$ and $\beta = v_2(b) > 0$. If (wlog) $\alpha \leq \beta$, then $\alpha < 3\beta$, and thus $v_2(b^3+a) = \alpha$; however, this is a power of two, which gets us into a contradiction.

Now, (wlog) we suppose that $a<b$ (you already handled the case where they are equal) and thus $2\leq x < y$, we have that $2^x | 2^y$, so $a^3+b|b^3+a$, i.e. $b^3+a \equiv 0 \mod (a^3+b)$. But $b \equiv -a^3 \mod (a^3+b)$; therefore $$ 0 \equiv b^3+a\equiv a-a^9 \mod 2^x.$$ Since $a$ is odd, this implies $2^x | a^8-1$.

If $x=2$, we have $a^3+b = 4$, and thus $a=1$ and $b=3$, which is not a solution. Therefore $x\geq3$.

If $x=3$, we have $a^3+b = 8$, and thus $a=1$ and $b=7$, which is not a solution. Therefore $x\geq4$.

If $x=4$, we have $a^3+b = 16$, and thus (remember that $a$ is odd) $a=1$ and $b=15$, which is not a solution. Therefore $x\geq5$.

Now, $a^8-1 = (a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)$. Moreover, we know that $v_2(a^2+1) = v_2(a^4+1) = 1$, thus $2^{x-2} | (a-1)(a+1)$.

Depending on the class of $a$ modulo $4$, we know that either $v_2(a+1) = 1$ or $v_2(a-1) = 1$, therefore $2^{x-3}|a\pm1$. This means that $a = k2^{x-3}\pm1$.

Now, if $k \geq 2$ or $k=1$ and the sign is a $+$, we have $$ 2^x = a^3+b = (k2^{x-3}\pm1)^3+b > (2^{x-3})^3 = 2^{3x-9} \implies x > 3x-9 \implies 2x < 9 \implies x \leq 4,$$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore, either $a=1$ or $a = 2^{x-3}-1$.

Suppose $a=1$, then $b = 2^x-1$, and thus $$(2^x-1)^3+1 = b^3+a=2^y \implies 2^{2x}-3\cdot 2^x + 3 = 2^{y-x};$$
Since $x>0$ and $y-x >0$, this is a contradiction.

This means that $a= 2^{x-3}-1$, and thus $$2^x = a^3 + b > a^3+a > (2^{x-3}-1)^3 + (2^{x-3}-1) = 2^{3x-9} - 3\cdot 2^{2x-6} + 4\cdot 2^{x-3}-2 = 2^{3x-9} - 3\cdot 2^{2x-6} + 2^{x-1}-2;$$ thus $$ 2^{x-1} + 2 + 3\cdot 2^{2x-6} > 2^{3x-9}.$$
Since $3<4$, we get $$2^{3x-9} < 2^{x-1} + 2^{2x-4} + 2.$$
Finally, $z^2 \geq 2z + 2 \iff (z-1)^2 \geq 3$, which is true for $z = 2^{x-2}$ (since $x\geq5$). Therefore $$2^{3x-9} < 2^{2x-3} \implies 3x-9 < 2x-3 \implies x<6.$$

This means that we only need to check $x=5$. This implies that $a = 2^{x-3}-1 = 3$ and $b = 2^x-a^3 = 32 - 27 = 5$. On the other hand, $b^3 + a = 125 + 3 = 128 = 2^7$.

Therefore the solutions $(a,b)$ are $(1,1)$ , $(3,5)$ and $(5,3)$. The correponding $c$ can be easily found.